# Is it possible to somehow subcategorize events in analyitcs?

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

Like title says is it possible to get that sub categories and sort them out in analytics?

For example we have event that says which city it was where it fired, and we have bunch of other events together with that one. Now we would like to all of events that fire in that City go into subcategory for it.

So basically if City present for all other events move them as subcategory of that city.

Comment: I'm not aware of any GA functionality for that.